# FirebaseTextRecognition with multiple Textview

Tags: android, firebase, textview, text-recognition

I'm learning how to use FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer, is't possible to insert few blocks of text to multiple TextView?

The link is where I'm getting started and learning. It worked and is displaying all text into 1 Textview. Then what if image has 4 blocks of texts, is't possible to seperate those 4 blocks of text into 4 different Textview? much help appreciated :) thanks.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0273WiUQPI

```
       private void processText(FirebaseVisionText text) {
        List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = text.getTextBlocks();
    //check if list is empty            
       if (blocks.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "empty text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
     //for loop the Textblock and insert text to textview
    for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock textBlock : text.getTextBlocks()) {
        String sText = textBlock.getText();
        textView.setText(sText);
    }
}

****Update****

**XML Code** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl_ml_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FirebaseTextML">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detectButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="detec" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_text"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_show_text_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_show_text_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_show_text_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


**Java code**
```

Declaration

```
LinearLayout mLlView;
Context mContext;


private void processText(FirebaseVisionText text) {
    mLlView.removeAllViews();
//        create a list to store the textblocks
    List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = text.getTextBlocks();
    if (blocks.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "empty text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    mContext  = this;
    for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock textBlock : text.getTextBlocks()) {
        String sText = textBlock.getText();
        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setText(sText);
        mLlView.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

**Result**
i able to split the texts by blocks, but how do I insert them into multiple textview?

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: I see a problem with your code

Comment: @user1241241 - would you mind elaborating it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a layout in which those `TextViews` should be laid and then insert them in a loop like this:

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock textBlock : text.getTextBlocks()) {
    TextView textView = TextView(context);
    textView.setText(textBlock.getText());
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i updated the question. Am I in the correct path?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct path"? Does the solution you currently have not work?

Comment: I have tested you solution you provided, it work and it will split the text into multiple line. But I would like it to be inserted into multiple Textview instead only 1 Textview. Are we discussing the right thing here?

Comment: But these are multiple textviews. Check in the layout inspector.

Comment: Hi, i just updated my expected result, i think it will provide clearer picture

Comment: What is the current result that you have?

Comment: based on the code I provided, all text will appear only in 1 textview. still trying how to separate other texts to another textviews

Comment: You're literally adding these textviews separately. There's more than one textview literally. You can check it in the layout inspector or maybe set padding on it and you'll see that there's more than one textview.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it from here. thanks for following up and assisting me. much appreciated

Comment: opps, forgotten to do that, sorry and thanks for the guide